# How to specify test dlls in TFS Build Server?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

The default behavior of TFS Build Server is copy all output, dlls, exes to the folder `C:\Builds\{Build_Agent_Number}\{Team_Project_Name}\{Build_Controller_Name}\Binaries`. I have customized the build process, not to copy to that folder but instead copy it to another, let say `C:\Builds\{Build_Agent_Number}\{Team_Project_Name}\{Build_Controller_Name}\Sources\Some_Folder\Some_Sub_Folder`.

The build process works as expected but the problem is all tests don't run. I debugged the build process template and found that it could not find test dlls. I want to know how can I specify the test dll location in the testsettings file or in the build process template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it on Find Test Assemblies activity in you Build Process Template workflow. It locates a little below the middle of the process.

1. Navigate to Find Test Assemblies activity inside Run MSTest for Test Assemblies.[image: Find Test Assemblies]
2. Pree <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the properties windows then change MatchPattern to the root path that contains assemblies you want to test. For example, `String.Format("{0}\{1}", MyCustomAssembliesPath, testAssembly.AssemblyFileSpec)`[image: Properties Windows]